# Handling Master/Slave on the Application Layer

Tags: php, mysql

So I am working on a legacy system, that had one database server. For reporting and to split the work load it has been moved to a Master / Slave setup. This process is done and seems to be working well with little to no lag between an insert or update on the master, and it being copied to the slave. The problem I have is the application layer with the PHP, I am using Centos 6.8, and it is fully updated with a php version 5.3.3, this leaves me no access to the mysqlnd_ms functions.

I cannot seem to get Centos to update the php version past 5.3.3, and I have looked everywhere for an application layer that I can incorporate for reading / writing look ups. My main concern is when there is data being inserted, I want to make sure that if I pull from that same table, it knows to use the master for that since it is not likely, that in a few milliseconds the slave has already been caught up.

What is standard procedure for this? Do we *need* to find a way to update the php, or is there a way we can do this in the application layer without doing some tricky updating of the php version.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this question has been to do this:

I already had a database class to do all queries with, so I added a check to the top of the **$db->query()** function to check if it was a select call, if it wasn't, it is auto-sent to the master. If it was a select call, it checks the cached version of *SECONDS_BEHIND_MASTER* that is checked every time the database is connected. I then stored the names of every table that is ever updated / inserted into, and when it was last done. Then when doing a SELECT statement it checks the tables in the select statement, vs the last time an update by that user was done to that table. If it was last updated prior to the seconds_behind_master it uses the slave. If the seconds_behind_master is ever 5 seconds or more, just use the master always.

It's not perfect but it is sending about 80% of the select calls now to the slave server, and that's good enough for my purposes at this time.